# Transform Array in Spark

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, rdd, spark-graphx

```
val degrees: VertexRDD[Int] = graph.degrees
val ngb=graph.collectNeighbors(EdgeDirection.Out)
val deg2 = degrees.leftOuterJoin(ngb)
```

Now i want a key/value pair RDD where key is degree and value is neighbor vertex id. 
Basically i want to change from (id,Array[1,2,3]) to {(id,1)(id,2)(id,3)}

I have tried nested map and creating a string for the outer map. I am stuck here. If anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update with the code you have tried so we can help you!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, got it myself.
Did flatMap(y => y) with identity function. It was so simple.